# OD Cost Matrix Settings (Arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst

I have what is hopefully a fairly simple question.

I am trying to run an OD cost matrix for every minute of a day for research I am performing. All of the settings will be the same for each run, except the time will change. I will be automating the process in Python. I know how to create a cost matrix with the settings, add the locations, and solve it all using Arcpy. However, I am hoping to be able to just change the time setting for each run without having to create a whole new cost matrix and add the locations again (similar to what you can do manually in ArcMap).

I have not been able to find a way to do this in Python (if there even is a way).

Comment: Can you provide your python code so far and tell us what has worked and hasn't worked in it?

Comment: Everything works in my code so far. For example, I have it set up to run an OD matrix for my origins/destinations on a Monday at 8:00am. In Arcpy, the only way I can figure out how to run an OD matrix on a Monday at 8:01am is to create a whole new OD matrix and load all of my locations again. I was just wondering if there was a way to just change the time setting of an OD matrix without having the create a whole new one and load locations again.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62028/creating-an-origin-destination-od-cost-matrix-using-arcpy?rq=1) helpful.

Comment: Paul, Thanks for pointing that article out. I already read it and it might be the route I will have to take, but that solution still requires me to create a new OD matrix and add my locations again for each new time. There is probably no other way to do, but I was hoping to just find a way to change an OD matrix settings in arcpy without actually creating a new matrix, if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are trying to do. Sadly, it doesn't seem possible based on how the tool is set up.

Comment: I didn't think so either, but I figured it was worth a shot to see if anyone else found a way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still interested in this, I ended up finding the solution:

> The ODCostMatrixSolverProperties object provides read and write access
>   to all the analysis properties of an OD cost matrix network analysis
>   layer. The object can be used to modify the desired analysis
>   properties of the OD cost matrix layer, and the corresponding layer
>   can be re-solved to determine the appropriate results. A new OD cost
>   matrix layer can be created using the Make OD Cost Matrix Layer
>   geoprocessing tool. Obtaining the ODCostMatrixSolverProperties object
>   from a new OD cost matrix layer allows you to reuse the existing layer
>   for subsequent analyses rather than create a new layer for each
>   analysis, which can be slow.
>
> After modifying the properties on the ODCostMatrixSolverProperties
>   object, the corresponding layer can be immediately used with other
>   functions and geoprocessing tools. There is no refresh or update of
>   the layer required to honor the changes modified through the object.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mr0000000r000000